# A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists...content deployment

Tags: content-deployment

SP 2010 - Trying to deploy a site collection from a local server (L) to a remote server (R).  After several attempts using REAL data, I created a site collection in L, using blank site template.  Created list "Dummy 3" with 1 item.  Created a site collection in R, blank template.

Set R to accept content deployment jobs, then created new path/job on L.  When creating the path, the connection to the R server is successful.  The job fails, with errors:

"An unexpected error has occurred."  Object: AnalyticsReports/Forms/AllItems.aspx (same error for other objects in that folder: Combine.aspx, DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx etc.)

"A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title."  Object: wfpub

I've repeated the steps above with many different newly created site collections (same collection title on L & R, same URL on L & R, different titles/URLS, etc.), always deleting the site collections that didn't work...always same results.

A check in SP Designer shows a folder called "wfpub", but it only contains 1 empty folder "Forms".  No idea what that is.  Can I delete it?  Also a folder AnalyticsReports with those aspx files under the Forms folder.  Also no idea what that is.  Delete?  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by creating the destination site collection with the template Custom - Select template later... option, rather than using the template Collaboration - Blank Site.

I hope that saves some frustration for someone.